# DllNotFoundException while using c++ dll in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I have used a native C++ DLL in Xamarin.Android using `[DLLImport]` but I am getting exception `System.DllNotFoundException`. I have used same way as I do in C#. Plz provide me some simple code which explains all steps so that I can know if something extra has to be done for Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/) page.

Comment: But this link is for ios. I am working in xamarin Android. Plz if i can get some help on this

Comment: Check [this](http://richzwaap.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/pinvoke-with-xamarin-and-android/) post

Answer (score 1):

If you importe your library and you linked it in your project
you should use.

`[DllImport ("__Internal")]`

Instead of using a name of your library.

`[DllImport ("LibraryName")]`